# List of Dataframes First Column to rownames

Tags: r, list

I have ...

```
X  <- list(df1  <- data.frame(A=c("CC","CC(=O)C","CC(=O)O"),conc=c(1.0,2.2,1.0),Vol=c(2,4.5,6),stringsAsFactors=FALSE), df2  <- data.frame(A=c("COC","O=CC"),conc=c(2.0,3.2),Vol=c(10,23),stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
X
[1]]
        A conc Vol
1      CC  1.0 2.0
2 CC(=O)C  2.2 4.5
3 CC(=O)O  1.0 6.0

[[2]]
     A conc Vol
1  COC  2.0  10
2 O=CC  3.2  23
```

and I want to change the first column to rownames.

I have tried the obvious,

```
X <-lapply(X,function(a) {rownames(a)  <- a$A})
```

but this doesn't work ...

I began experimenting with the mapply function but I didn't get very far ...

Comment: You want something like `lapply(X,function(a){a$A <- rownames(a); a})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming when you said, "I want to change the first column to rownames" that you want to define the `rownames` with column `A` and drop column `A`.

```
lapply(X, function(df) {
    #new df without rowname col
    df_out <- df[,-1]
    #set rownames as first col from input df
    rownames(df_out) <- df[[1]]
    df_out
})
```

If you want to set column `A` to the current rownames then the code in @Sotos comment is a possible answer.

Comment: Or simply `lapply(X, '[', -1)`

Comment: @user1945827 two reasons. 1. You got the assigning part reverse. You are currently trying to assign the values of column `A` to the rownames (rather than the other way around) and 2. You have to return the data frame `a`. If you see my comment it will be clearer.

Comment: Modifying your code to return `a` will accomplish mostly the same thing as the `lapply` in my answer (column `A` will still be around in the list) `X <-lapply(X,function(a) {rownames(a)  <- a$A; a})`

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using dplyr and tibble `column_to_rownames`

```
X  <- list(df1  <- data.frame(A=c("CC","CC(=O)C","CC(=O)O"),conc=c(1.0,2.2,1.0),Vol=c(2,4.5,6),stringsAsFactors=FALSE), df2  <- data.frame(A=c("COC","O=CC"),conc=c(2.0,3.2),Vol=c(10,23),stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

X <- lapply(X, column_to_rownames, "A")
```